# Is the trace of an idempotent matrix a sum of idempotents?

Tags: matrices, commutative-algebra, trace

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $n$ a positive integer, and $A$ an idempotent $n$ by $n$ matrix with entries in $R$.

Is the trace of $A$ necessarily a sum of idempotents of $R$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a positive answer to the question follows immediately from [this MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/67352/461) of Neil Strickland.

**EDIT** (Aug 8'14). Here are more details. (This almost a copy and paste of Neil Strickland's post.)

Let $x$ and $y$ be indeterminates, and put 
$$
B(x)=xA+1-A\in R[A,x],\quad f(x)=\det(B(x))\in R[x].
$$ 
We find that 
$$
B(xy)=B(x)B(y)\in R[A,x,y],\quad f(xy)=f(x)f(y)\in R[x,y].
$$ 
We also have $f(1)=1$. It follows that 
$$
f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^me_i\,x^i
$$ 
for some elements $e_i\in R$ which are orthogonal idempotents, *i.e.* 
$$
e_i\,e_j=\delta_{ij}\,e_i,\quad \sum_ie_i=1.
$$ 
We also have 
$$
\text{tr}(A)=f'(1)=\sum_ii\,e_i.
$$